# Saving objects with constructor to xml

Tags: c#, xml, unity-game-engine, serialization, deserialization

Hello everyone i need some help what do i need to change in this code to be able to serialize (save) this file?
I'm trying to create a inventory file that will save crafted items (this one in particular saves crafted components) i have a almost identical code for saving crafted weapons. Searching the net i couldn't find a way to serialize this object because it uses parameters, but i need to add data into that list and save it. Is there a way around it ? if yes how ? THANK YOU !

the error im getting is

**InvalidOperationException: ComponentDB.ItemEntry cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class ComponentDB : MonoBehaviour
{

    public ItemDatabase itemDB;
    public string Slot;
    public static ComponentDB ins;

    void Awake()
    {
        ins = this;
        Slot = "Slot1";
    }

    public void SaveItems()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemDatabase));
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Save/" + Slot + "CraftedComp.xml", FileMode.Create);
        serializer.Serialize(stream, itemDB);
        stream.Close();
    }
    public void LoadItems()
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(ItemDatabase));
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(Application.dataPath + "/StreamingAssets/Save/" + Slot + "CraftedComp.xml", FileMode.Open);
        itemDB = serializer.Deserialize(stream) as ItemDatabase;
        stream.Close();
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ItemEntry
    {
        public string Name;
        public string Data;
        public int Amount;


        public ItemEntry(string iName, string idata, int iAmount)
        {
            Name = iName;
            Data = idata;
            Amount = iAmount;
        }
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ItemDatabase
    {
        public List<ItemEntry> list = new List<ItemEntry>();
    }

    public void ManageItemsInv(string input_name, string input_list,  int input_amount)
    {

        ins.itemDB.list.Add(new ItemEntry(input_name, input_list,  input_amount));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need `XmlRoot`, `XmlAttribute`, `XmlArray` and `XmlArrayItem` attributes, see [XmlSerialization](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Saving_and_Loading_Data:_XmlSerializer)

Comment: the loading writing and loading from other files that have similar code work. the only difference in this and the other files is the constructor public ItemEntry(string iName, string idata, int iAmount)... and the public void ManageItemsInv(string input_name, string input_list,  int input_amount) the error im getting is InvalidOperationException: ComponentDB.ItemEntry cannot be serialized because it does not have a parameterless constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code are almost OK, except: you missed a parameterless constructor for ItemEntry, then you could not serialize it.

Solution is quite simple: create a parameterless constructor in ItemEntry class:

```
        [Serializable]
        public class ItemEntry
        {
            public string Name;
            public string Data;
            public int Amount;

            //parameterless constructor for XmlSerializer
            public ItemEntry()
            {
            }

            public ItemEntry(string iName, string idata, int iAmount)
            {
                Name = iName;
                Data = idata;
                Amount = iAmount;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks i couldnt find any info on this and i a bit of a noob with c# especially with objects and serialization.